# API Platform Many to One not expecting IRI

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, openapi, api-platform.com

I am using API Platform with Symfony for my backend.
I have 2 entities linked with a ManyToOne relationship, Booking and User.
A user can have one or many bookings.
I also have another entity Service, with a OneToMany relationship with Booking.

When I try to test the POST for Bookings on the Swagger interface I get an error on the IRI format for services but not for the others.
Nothing works as input for the fields related to User (provider, client).

I don't understand why it doesn't work. I only get a 400 error.

Here are my entities :
Booking:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\BookingRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"booking:read"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"booking:write"}},
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get",
 *         "post"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_USER')"}
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get",
 *         "put"={"security"="is_granted('edit', object)"},
 *         "patch"={"security"="is_granted('edit', object)"},
 *         "delete"={"security"="is_granted('delete', object)"}
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=BookingRepository::class)
 */
class Booking
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @Groups("booking:read")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     *
     * @Groups({"booking:read","booking:write"})
     */
    private $bookingDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime_immutable")
     *
     * @Groups("booking:read")
     */
    private $reservedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Groups({"booking:read","booking:write"})
     */
    private $location;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="time")
     *
     * @Groups({"booking:read","booking:write"})
     */
    private $startTime;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="time")
     *
     * @Groups({"booking:read","booking:write"})
     */
    private $endTime;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="bookingsAsProvider")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     *
     * @Groups({"booking:read","booking:write"})
     */
    private $provider;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="bookingsAsClient")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     *
     * @Groups({"booking:read","booking:write"})
     */
    private $client;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Service::class, inversedBy="bookings")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"booking:read","booking:write"})
     */
    private $service;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"booking:read","booking:write"})
     */
    private $state;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @Groups({"booking:read","booking:write"})
     */
    private $read;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getBookingDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->bookingDate;
    }

    public function setBookingDate(\DateTimeInterface $bookingDate): self
    {
        $this->bookingDate = $bookingDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getReservedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->reservedAt;
    }

    public function setReservedAt(\DateTimeImmutable $reservedAt): self
    {
        $this->reservedAt = $reservedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLocation(): ?string
    {
        return $this->location;
    }

    public function setLocation(string $location): self
    {
        $this->location = $location;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStartTime(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->startTime;
    }

    public function setStartTime(\DateTimeInterface $startTime): self
    {
        $this->startTime = $startTime;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEndTime(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->endTime;
    }

    public function setEndTime(\DateTimeInterface $endTime): self
    {
        $this->endTime = $endTime;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProvider(): ?User
    {
        return $this->provider;
    }

    public function setProvider(?User $provider): self
    {
        $this->provider = $provider;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getClient(): ?User
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

    public function setClient(?User $client): self
    {
        $this->client = $client;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getService(): ?Service
    {
        return $this->service;
    }

    public function setService(?Service $service): self
    {
        $this->service = $service;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getState(): ?int
    {
        return $this->state;
    }

    public function setState(int $state): self
    {
        $this->state = $state;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRead(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->read;
    }

    public function setRead(bool $read): self
    {
        $this->read = $read;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

User:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiSubresource;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"user:read"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"user:write"}},
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or object == user"},
 *         "post"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN_FRONTEND')"}
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *          "get",
 *          "put"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or object == user"},
 *          "patch"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or object == user"},
 *          "delete"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"},
 *          "get_by_role" = {
 *              "method" = "GET",
 *              "path" = "/user/{role}",
 *              "controller" = User::class,
 *              "read"=false,
 *          "openapi_context" = {
 *              "parameters" = {
 *                  {
 *                  "name" = "role",
 *                  "in" = "path",
 *                  "description" = "The role of a user",
 *                  "type" = "string",
 *                  "required" = true,
 *                  "example"= "ROLE_PARENT",
 *                  },
 *              },
 *              },
 *     },
 *     },
 * )
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @Groups({"user:read","service:read","booking:read"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     *
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write","businessRelationship:read","service:read"})
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     *
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write","businessRelationship:read","service:read"})
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @Groups("user:write")
     *
     * @SerializedName("password")
     */
    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     *
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write","businessRelationship:read","service:read","booking:read"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     *
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write","businessRelationship:read","service:read","booking:read"})
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     *
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write","businessRelationship:read","service:read"})
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     *
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write","businessRelationship:read","service:read"})
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     *
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write","businessRelationship:read","service:read"})
     */
    private $facebook;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     *
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write","businessRelationship:read","service:read"})
     */
    private $instagram;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     *
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write","businessRelationship:read","service:read"})
     */
    private $linkedin;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     *
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write","businessRelationship:read","service:read"})
     */
    private $twitter;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     *
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write","businessRelationship:read","service:read"})
     */
    private $pinterest;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     *
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write","businessRelationship:read","service:read"})
     */
    private $website;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     *
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write","businessRelationship:read","service:read"})
     */
    private $tagline;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     *
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write","businessRelationship:read","service:read"})
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Address::class, mappedBy="client",cascade={"persist"})
     *
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     * @ApiSubresource
     */
    private $addresses;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Service::class, mappedBy="performer")
     * @ApiSubresource
     */
    private $servicesAsPerformer;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Service::class, mappedBy="owner")
     * @ApiSubresource
     */
    private $servicesAsOwner;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=BusinessRelationship::class, mappedBy="partnerA")
     * @ApiSubresource
     */
    private $businessRelationshipsPartnerA;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=BusinessRelationship::class, mappedBy="partnerB")
     * @ApiSubresource
     */
    private $businessRelationshipsPartnerB;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Booking::class, mappedBy="provider")
     * @ApiSubresource
     */
    private $bookingsAsProvider;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Booking::class, mappedBy="client")
     * @ApiSubresource
     */
    private $bookingsAsClient;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Schedule::class, mappedBy="provider")
     * @ApiSubresource
     */
    private $schedules;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=UserCategory::class, mappedBy="provider")
     * @ApiSubresource
     *
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $userCategories;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $profilePicture;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=16777215, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $gallery;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Notification::class, mappedBy="userOrigin")
     * @ApiSubresource
     *
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $notificationsUserOrigin;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Notification::class, mappedBy="userTarget")
     * @ApiSubresource
     *
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $notificationsUserTarget;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $resetToken;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addresses = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->servicesAsPerformer = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->servicesAsOwner = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->businessRelationshipsPartnerA = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->businessRelationshipsPartnerB = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->bookingsAsProvider = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->bookingsAsClient = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->schedules = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->userCategories = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->notificationsUserOrigin = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->notificationsUserTarget = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated since Symfony 5.3, use getUserIdentifier instead
     */
//    public function getUsername(): string
//    {
//        return (string) $this->email;
//    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returning a salt is only needed, if you are not using a modern
     * hashing algorithm (e.g. bcrypt or sodium) in your security.yaml.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt(): ?string
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname(?string $firstname): self
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    public function setPhone(?string $phone): self
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFacebook(): ?string
    {
        return $this->facebook;
    }

    public function setFacebook(?string $facebook): self
    {
        $this->facebook = $facebook;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInstagram(): ?string
    {
        return $this->instagram;
    }

    public function setInstagram(?string $instagram): self
    {
        $this->instagram = $instagram;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLinkedin(): ?string
    {
        return $this->linkedin;
    }

    public function setLinkedin(?string $linkedin): self
    {
        $this->linkedin = $linkedin;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTwitter(): ?string
    {
        return $this->twitter;
    }

    public function setTwitter(?string $twitter): self
    {
        $this->twitter = $twitter;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPinterest(): ?string
    {
        return $this->pinterest;
    }

    public function setPinterest(?string $pinterest): self
    {
        $this->pinterest = $pinterest;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getWebsite(): ?string
    {
        return $this->website;
    }

    public function setWebsite(?string $website): self
    {
        $this->website = $website;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTagline(): ?string
    {
        return $this->tagline;
    }

    public function setTagline(?string $tagline): self
    {
        $this->tagline = $tagline;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPlainPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    public function setPlainPassword(?string $plainPassword): self
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Address[]
     */
    public function getAddresses(): Collection
    {
        return $this->addresses;
    }

    public function addAddress(Address $address): self
    {
        if (!$this->addresses->contains($address)) {
            $this->addresses[] = $address;
            $address->setClient($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAddress(Address $address): self
    {
        if ($this->addresses->removeElement($address)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($address->getClient() === $this) {
                $address->setClient(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function hasRoles(string $roles): bool
    {
        return in_array($roles, $this->roles);
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Service[]
     */
    public function getServicesAsPerformer(): Collection
    {
        return $this->servicesAsPerformer;
    }

    public function addServicesAsPerformer(Service $servicesAsPerformer): self
    {
        if (!$this->servicesAsPerformer->contains($servicesAsPerformer)) {
            $this->servicesAsPerformer[] = $servicesAsPerformer;
            $servicesAsPerformer->addPerformer($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeServicesAsPerformer(Service $servicesAsPerformer): self
    {
        if ($this->servicesAsPerformer->removeElement($servicesAsPerformer)) {
            $servicesAsPerformer->removePerformer($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Service[]
     */
    public function getServicesAsOwner(): Collection
    {
        return $this->servicesAsOwner;
    }

    public function addServicesAsOwner(Service $servicesAsOwner): self
    {
        if (!$this->servicesAsOwner->contains($servicesAsOwner)) {
            $this->servicesAsOwner[] = $servicesAsOwner;
            $servicesAsOwner->setOwner($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeServicesAsOwner(Service $servicesAsOwner): self
    {
        if ($this->servicesAsOwner->removeElement($servicesAsOwner)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($servicesAsOwner->getOwner() === $this) {
                $servicesAsOwner->setOwner(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|BusinessRelationship[]
     */
    public function getBusinessRelationshipsPartnerA(): Collection
    {
        return $this->businessRelationshipsPartnerA;
    }

    public function addBusinessRelationshipsPartnerA(BusinessRelationship $businessRelationshipsPartnerA): self
    {
        if (!$this->businessRelationshipsPartnerA->contains($businessRelationshipsPartnerA)) {
            $this->businessRelationshipsPartnerA[] = $businessRelationshipsPartnerA;
            $businessRelationshipsPartnerA->setPartnerA($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeBusinessRelationshipsPartnerA(BusinessRelationship $businessRelationshipsPartnerA): self
    {
        if ($this->businessRelationshipsPartnerA->removeElement($businessRelationshipsPartnerA)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($businessRelationshipsPartnerA->getPartnerA() === $this) {
                $businessRelationshipsPartnerA->setPartnerA(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|BusinessRelationship[]
     */
    public function getBusinessRelationshipsPartnerB(): Collection
    {
        return $this->businessRelationshipsPartnerB;
    }

    public function addBusinessRelationshipsPartnerB(BusinessRelationship $businessRelationshipsPartnerB): self
    {
        if (!$this->businessRelationshipsPartnerB->contains($businessRelationshipsPartnerB)) {
            $this->businessRelationshipsPartnerB[] = $businessRelationshipsPartnerB;
            $businessRelationshipsPartnerB->setPartnerB($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeBusinessRelationshipsPartnerB(BusinessRelationship $businessRelationshipsPartnerB): self
    {
        if ($this->businessRelationshipsPartnerB->removeElement($businessRelationshipsPartnerB)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($businessRelationshipsPartnerB->getPartnerB() === $this) {
                $businessRelationshipsPartnerB->setPartnerB(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Booking[]
     */
    public function getBookingsAsProvider(): Collection
    {
        return $this->bookingsAsProvider;
    }

    public function addBookingsAsProvider(Booking $bookingsAsProvider): self
    {
        if (!$this->bookingsAsProvider->contains($bookingsAsProvider)) {
            $this->bookingsAsProvider[] = $bookingsAsProvider;
            $bookingsAsProvider->setProvider($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeBookingsAsProvider(Booking $bookingsAsProvider): self
    {
        if ($this->bookingsAsProvider->removeElement($bookingsAsProvider)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($bookingsAsProvider->getProvider() === $this) {
                $bookingsAsProvider->setProvider(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Booking[]
     */
    public function getBookingsAsClient(): Collection
    {
        return $this->bookingsAsClient;
    }

    public function addBookingsAsClient(Booking $bookingsAsClient): self
    {
        if (!$this->bookingsAsClient->contains($bookingsAsClient)) {
            $this->bookingsAsClient[] = $bookingsAsClient;
            $bookingsAsClient->setClient($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeBookingsAsClient(Booking $bookingsAsClient): self
    {
        if ($this->bookingsAsClient->removeElement($bookingsAsClient)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($bookingsAsClient->getClient() === $this) {
                $bookingsAsClient->setClient(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
[...]
}
```

Service:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiSubresource;
use App\Repository\ServiceRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"service:read"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"service:write"}},
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get",
 *         "post"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_USER')"}
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get",
 *         "put"={"security"="is_granted('edit', object)"},
 *         "patch"={"security"="is_granted('edit', object)"},
 *         "delete"={"security"="is_granted('delete', object)"}
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ServiceRepository::class)
 */
class Service
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * 
     * @Groups({"service:read","schedule:read"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * 
     * @Groups({"service:read", "service:write","schedule:read"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     *
     * @Groups({"service:read", "service:write","schedule:read"})
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     *
     * @Groups({"service:read", "service:write","schedule:read"})
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Address::class, inversedBy="services")
     *
     * @Groups({"service:read", "service:write"})
     * @ApiSubresource
     */
    private $addresses;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="servicesAsPerformer")
     * @Groups({"service:read", "service:write","schedule:read"})
     */
    private $performer;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="servicesAsOwner")
     * @Groups({"service:read", "service:write","schedule:read"})
     */
    private $owner;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Schedule::class, mappedBy="services")
     * @Groups({"service:read", "service:write"})
     * @ApiSubresource
     */
    private $schedules;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Booking::class, mappedBy="service")
     */
    private $bookings;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addresses = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->performer = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->schedules = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->bookings = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    [...]

}
```

Here are the JSON inputs I tried with the response I get :

1. Error 400  **"Syntax Error"**

```
{
  "bookingDate": "2022-11-14T14:59:49.322Z",
  "location": "string",
  "startTime": "2022-11-14T14:59:49.322Z",
  "endTime": "2022-11-14T14:59:49.322Z",
  "provider": "string",
  "client": "string",
  "service": "\api\services\725",
  "state": 0,
  "read": true
}
```

2. Error 400  **"Invalid IRI "string"."**

```
{
  "bookingDate": "2022-11-14T14:59:49.322Z",
  "location": "string",
  "startTime": "2022-11-14T14:59:49.322Z",
  "endTime": "2022-11-14T14:59:49.322Z",
  "provider": "string",
  "client": "string",
  "service": "string",
  "state": 0,
  "read": true
}
```

I really don't see why for service it expects an IRI format, while not for client and provider.

Comment: `"service": "\api\services\725"` feels wrong, `"service": "/api/services/725"` looks better.

Comment: Thanks but it's the right format for IRI string :)

Comment: You sure ? I tried to replace one of my IRIs `/` with \ in a project of mine, the route went from 201 to 400 Syntax Error.

Comment: Yes, I get the IRI error when I replace the \ with /.

Comment: I'm so sorry, you were right !  The error I was getting was with the "read" field. Thank you for your help :) (Although, I still don't know what clearly is the issue with that field)